# Restart USB port WITHOUT reboot (DevCon)

Tags: usb, windows-scripting, devcon, device-instance-id

***UNNECESSARY BACKGROUND INFO:*** I purchased a new USB microphone (Samson Q2U) and I am having an issue where every time I (re)boot my PC, the mic does not work (it does receive power) until I unplug and re-plug the microphone from the USB port.

**Now onto the important part:** I wanted to disable/enable or remove/add the USB port where my microphone is plugged in using `devcon`.

I tried `devcon restart` and `devcon remove` (followed by `devcon rescan`) but both seem to require a system reboot to function, which is of course not at all what I am looking for as the error occurs when rebooting the system.

I have tried this with the actual USB port the microphone is plugged in, the instance path of the microphone itself (under Device Manager > audio inputs and outputs) and the USB Root Hub where the USB port is a part of. Both trying it with the USB port and USB Root Hub required a system reboot, thus it was not effective for me. Trying it with the microphone itself, it restarted bur did not solve my problem.

Is there any way of disabling/enabling or restarting the USB Root Hub or USB port where the microphone is plugged in WITHOUT A REBOOT using `devcon`? Or any other methods other than `devcon` that might work? I was planning on making a script that fixes my issue and put it inside the startup folder.

**I am aware of the couple other threads on this forum that have about the same question as I do but these did not resolve my issue and were pretty old as well so I wanted to make a new thread on this topic.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known issue, you need to update the firmware of Q2U and it will completely fix it.
Here's the link: https://samsontech.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360045374974

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked! You solved one of my first world problems... :D
Where did you get this anyways? I felt like I searched half the internet for this fix...

Comment: I cheated and asked Samson's tech support for a fix directly, lol